# How do I implement Thread safety in a multi-server system?

Tags: java, database, thread-safety, locking

I am working on a project where I have to check the value of a particular property in a DB table (and throw an exception if it is more than 1). Each instance must be checked. I have been asked to make sure to keep the process thread-safe in a multi-server setup. So Locking at the DB level is the only way possible since the DB is shared between all the servers. How do I execute this? How does SELECT ... FOR UPDATE work? and should I worry about where I release the lock (i.e., after or before commit or rollback?)

```
if(A.getPropertyX() > 1) {
        throw new LimitExceededException();
}
```

Keeping this under synchronized block works fine if requests come from multiple threads and a single server. But if multiple requests come parallelly from multiple servers, the logic fails.

Comment: You can check out *row-based locking* for best performance regarding this. Another suggestion: find a way to divide up requests to servers by a pattern (partitioning), and concerning data, servers can only access their portion of data they're given in initialization. then give each server two possibilities for handling a request: either handle it himself, in ram, only working on the data he was assigned, or send/relay/proxy the request to another server that in turn does his operations on his data set only, without DB locking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit like 'how to build a house' - thread safety is an incredibly complicated topic.

To make matters worse, you're not actually asking about thread safety. The idiom 'thread safety' inherently implies "single server".

> So lock at the DB level is the only way possible since the DB is shared between all the servers.

That's a problem; DBs out of the box do not have locks. Or rather, they do, but it's not part of the SQL spec.

> How does `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` work?

Depends on the database, the transaction settings / isolation level, and depending on database engine, the table engine. Most of all, it makes no guarantees other than about data consistency, so trying to use `FOR UPDATE` to lock out your app **is not going to work** - in the sense that it may actually 'work', but is dependent on such a gigantic sack of configurations and versions that it'll be extremely fragile and hard to understand without a ton of documentation ('This works because mysql v4.5 using the innodb table engine, with the JDBC driver at v8.12 configured in this transaction isolation level, after extensive testing, indicates that `FOR UPDATE` freezes out the connection until committed, so we can use it for locking...' - that kind of documentation. You don't want this).

> and should I worry about where I release the lock (i.e., after or before commit or rollback?)

**IF** `.. FOR UPDATE` locks (big if!) the only way to 'unlock' it, is to commit (and you can't commit but not unlock it. Commit and unlock go together). Rollback also unlocks, of course.

> But if multiple requests come parallelly from multiple servers, the logic fails. I'm supposed to throw an exception even if that's the case.

That's stupid. You should just retry if that's the case.

### Let's break it down

What do you really need? Presumably, if all communication goes through the database, what you really need is a consistent view of the data. You don't actually need locks at all. Here is an example of a banking system that explains what I mean.

Imagine a bank. On the outside, there's an ATM. On the inside, someone at the desk.

You're planning to fleece your bank. You have $100,- on your account.

You hand your bank account card to your accomplice (they also have an account, but it's at $0), and enter the bank with your identity document.

You ask the teller to transfer 100 bucks to your accomplice. At that exact same moment in time, you ask your accompice to sort of observe through the window and attempt to withdraw a $10 note from the ATM using your bank account card at the exact same time.

If the bank software is **not** written well, then depending on timing you two may succeed and after all is done, the status is:

- Your accomplice has $100 on their account.
- You have $90 on your account.
- Your accomplice is now holding a $10 bill.
- The bank just got fleeced for 100 bucks and they'll never know.

Presumably what you've been tasked to do is write the software such that this cannot happen - that the bank cannot be fleeced this way.

There are many ways to solve this problem, but by miles the best way to do it is:

- Use the TransactionLevel.SERIALIZABLE.
- Use a retry-capable database framework.

Locks is another solution, but locks are an outdated concept that doesn't scale well and isn't how modern database engines work.

### What is 'SERIALIZABLE'? What is a transaction isolation level?

transactions try to make guarantees, but it's not as simple as 'now it is atomic'. There are these concepts known as dirty reads and phantom reads. The isolation level tells the database engines exactly which guarantees you desire. The SERIALIZABLE level is the 'heaviest' level and gives you *all* the guarantees. No dirty reads, no non-repeatable reads, no phantom reads. You set it on the connection like so:

```
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
```

Not doing this is a very bad idea: Trying to keep in mind exactly which guarantees you do and do not have whilst writing your bank software is extremely difficult, and writing tests that catch failures in your code is extremely complicated. It's a formula for disaster. SERIALIZABLE gives you guarantees.

### The concept of MVCC and retry

The problem is, to prevent phantom reads, the database really just has to lock everything anytime anybody does anything. Even a really simple `SELECT x FROM foo WHERE unid = 5;` requires locking **the entire `foo` table** in order to properly make these guarantees, resulting in dog slow databases. But if you don't lock it all, then the programmer has to juggle the locks using `... FOR UPDATE` and this really STILL doesn't give great guarantees. To make this more applied, here's the key trickery that needs to be prevented - this is what phantom reads are all about. The teller's 'transfer money from one account to another' software looks something like this:

```
String from = "Venkat";
String to = "Accomplice";
int amount = 100;
int fromBalance = query("SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user = ?", from);
int toBalance = query("SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user = ?", to);

if (fromBalance < amount) throw new InsufficientFunds();
fromBalance -= amount;
toBalance += amount;

update("UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE user = ?", fromBalance, from);
update("UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE user = ?", toBalance, to);
```

The problem is, imagine that in between the SELECT and UPDATE statements, the ATM does its select (registering that you have $100 in your account), and then whilst the ATM is grabbing a 10 dollar note from the hopper, you wrap up the UPDATE inside, and then finally the ATM 'updates' your account balance and sets it to 90. That's the problem.

The key aspect you want here is that the read is so-called repeatable: Basically, at the very instant you COMMIT, you want for **ALL** the SELECT statements you ran in that transaction to have the same result if you ran them again right now, except for the effects of all UPDATE/INSERT statements you ran in this very transaction.

One way to do that, is to use e.g. FOR UPDATE or just use extremely aggressive locking behaviour: Have those SELECT statements lock those rows out until you're done.

The problem with locks is that this doesn't really work. Imagine you did this query:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts where amount > 100 FOR UPDATE;
```

And then later, whilst the transaction that ran the above statement is still open, some other transaction adds a new row to the database (with amount 0) and commits this, and then yet another transaction UPDATEs that row and sets the amount to 150, and THEN you commit this first transaction with the `WHERE amount > 100` query.

This is, depending on your exact needs, **a thread safety violation** - your SELECT query failed to give you that one row.

This explains the name SERIALIZABLE: It means: You can imagine all interaction with the database as if it was all 'serialized': First this transaction was started, ran, closed, and only then the next transaction started, ran, closed. It doesn't have to *actually* occur that way (where any open connection will just hang until all transactions are closed), but the point of SERIALIZABLE is that you can explain events in that manner and all returned data and updates work out just like that.

It's really, really hard to write the bank software properly without it: That `FOR UPDATE` stuff cannot actually work unless you just lock the entire table every time. Which is ridiculously inefficient.

Fortunately, that's NOT how modern DBs work.

They instead use the same concept that your network cables use: Detect, retry, exponential backoff.

Here's what actually happens in a modern DB engine (and you don't need .. FOR UPDATE):

- Upon select and co, no locks are applied at all. Locks are expensive, after all, and `... FOR UPDATE` is error-prone (it's easy to forget, and hard to test that you needed it), so you really want this protection for all select statements, not just the ones you hand-picked using `.. FOR UPDATE`.
- When you commit, the DB does a check that all the results it returned for all the queries that were executed within this transaction would still be returning the same result.
- If that is the case, great, the commit succeeds. If that is NOT the case, however, a Retry ERROR is generated instead.

What does retry mean? Well, it's in the word: You just.. start over.

This is how the ATM+Teller situation would work out with the retry concept (Let's say you have $100, your accomplice has 0, and you want to transfer 40 bucks with the teller, and withdraw a $10 note from the ATM):

- The teller computer opens a transaction.
- The teller computer fetches your current account balance, as well as your accomplice's (100 - 0).
- The teller computer updates your balance to 40 and accomplice to 60. (no commit yet).
- The ATM computer opens a transaction.
- The ATM computer reads your balance and still sees 100 (the teller session hasn't committed yet, after all).
- The ATM computer preps 10 bucks in the hopper and is about to open the door.
- The teller computer commits.
- The ATM computer commits the transaction (wants to write 90 to your account balance), but gets a retry failure: One of the selects it did (namely, `SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user = you` now returns something else). So it just starts over: It reads your balance (now 60), subtracts 10, UPDATEs your account balance to 50, and commits. This time it works great.
- Because the transaction worked out, it opens the door and spits out 10 bucks.

All is well: 40 bucks was transferred, 10 dollars were spit out from the ATM, your balance is now 50, your accompice's balance is 10.

And all that without any locks!

So how to do this in java? Well, it'd look something like:

```
public class Atm {
  void withdraw(int accountId, int amount) throws SQLException {
    while (true) {
      try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
        int balance = con.exec("SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE...");
        if (balance < amount) throw new InsuffientFunds();
        balance -= amount;
        con.exec("UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE ....", balance);
      } catch (SQLException e) {
        // if e is retry, which depends on your DB engine...
        continue; // start over, jump to the top of while loop.
        // else..
        throw e; // actually throw the exception.
    }
  }
}
```

But, computers can be annoyingly consistent so if the teller computer and the ATM computer keep retrying they may, forever, get in each others way. So, you ALSO need to roll some dice and wait a random amount (and increment the size of the dice you're rolling on future repeats).

This is annoying. In fact, JDBC is annoying. It's not really meant for direct use like this.

Get a library that tackles all these issues such as [JDBI](https://jdbi.org). Just follow that link, right there on the top of the page the solution is there: You pass a LAMBDA (that `->` thing), and JDBI will take care of rerunning that code if needed.

Voila!

This gets you:

- Absolute safety - it is not possible for you to fleece the bank.
- No need to carefully pick out which selects need FOR UPDATE and which don't.
- No locks - everything will be nice and speedy.
- You can do serializable transaction levels with retry from many apps and many servers, all to the same DB engine.

The one caveat:

- Your DB code needs to be 'idempotent' - there should be no difference between running it once and running it 50 times. This can be hard to test (but not as hard as the locking stuff, fortunately).

Comment: You have explained that SERIALIZABLE is way better than SELECT ... FOR UPDATE. But given that SERIALIZABLE locks the whole table, what if another thread needs to retrieve a different value from the same table? Won't it delay the other threads which might become a huge delay issue in the multi-server client architecture?

Comment: _But given that SERIALIZABLE locks the whole table_ No it doesn't. Where are you getting this from? The answer explains in lots of detail how optimistic locking works ('optimistic locking' is a bit of misnomer. It doesn't lock). Extremely badly written, outdated, or overly simplistic DBs which don't support optimistic locking, yeah, they pretty much lock the world. You can't write bank software in such DBs. At all. Don't try with e.g .`FOR UPDATE` - it won't result in consistent data. The bank will get fleeced.